# Class of fractal curves derived from recursion on the base-2 representation of the integers

Tags: recurrence-relations, fractals

Consider the recurrence

> $\displaystyle
> T(n) = \begin{cases}
> 1 &\text{if } n = 0 \\
> 0 &\text{if } n = 1 \\
> T(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) + T(n \bmod 2) &\text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $

If you plot the value of this recurrence at the nonnegative integers, you get a fractal curve:

[image]

(The red line is $\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$; if you set $T(1)=1$ instead of $T(1)=0$, the recurrence degenerates to that function.)

Does this fractal have a name?  Is it a member of a more general class of curves?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that "fractal" is the correct term for this curve, in spite of the seeming self-similarity. If we plot your curve over the interval $[0,2^m]$ for several choices of $m$, we find that the lengths are $2^{m+1}-2$:

[image]

As the curves roughly double in length with each step, we'd expect a dimension of 1.

In the context of fractal geometry, it might make more sense to scale these curves so that each lies over the unit interval. If we plot them in correct aspect ratio, we see a picture that looks like so:

[image]

Note that the limiting object is just the unit interval; the dimension is again 1.

Comment: You're considering the entire domain of the recurrence, but isn't it more interesting if we consider intervals [2^n, 2^(n+1) - 1] for successive values of n as successive iterations of the fractal generator?

Comment: Hmm... I. think I'm considering the limiting object when we grab pieces over the intervals $[0,2^n]$. I don't think changing the intervals to $[2^n,2^{n+1}-1]$ would make a huge difference. In any event, if we want to apply the ideas of fractal geometry, then it's natural to consider a limit of some sort.